# differential equation with the constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation 
$$xy'-3y=A$$ 
where $A$ is constant?

I know how to solve it when the constant is zero, but how can I solve it with given that $A$ is a constant?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If it werent for A this would be             https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Euler_equation.Every nonhomgenous linear equation can be solved by solving the homogenous part, then finding a particular solution for the nonhomogenous. Adding those two solutions is the general solution

Answer (score 2):

A first order separable ODE has the form of $N(y) y' = M(x)$.

When calculating this:  $$N(y) = \frac{1}{A+3y}$$ and

$$M(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

This would be

$$\frac{1}{A+3y}y'= \frac{1}{x}$$

Now try to use integrals and then seperate y.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let new variable $w=y+\dfrac{A}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by noticing that $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}.$ Therefore:
$$xy'-3y=A \Rightarrow x \frac{dy}{dx}-3y = A \Rightarrow x \frac{dy}{dx} = 3y + A.$$

Now, considering that $dx$ and $dy$ can be used as "standard numbers", we can arrange the previous equation in order to have everything that depends on $x$ on the right, and everything that depends on $y$ on the left:

$$x \frac{dy}{dx} = 3y + A \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{3y+A} = \frac{dx}{x}.$$

Given this equation, we can integrate both terms:

$$\int \frac{dy}{3y+A} = \int \frac{dx}{x}.$$

Solving the previous indefinite integrals, we get:

$$\frac{1}{3}\log(3y+A) + c_1 = \log(x) + c_2,$$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are generic real numbers.

Notice that the previous equation can be rewritten as follows:

$$\frac{1}{3}\log(3y+A) + c_1 = \log(x) + c_2 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{3}\log(3y+A) = \log(x) + c_2 - c_1 = \log(x) + C,$$

where $C = c_2 - c_1.$ Moreover:

$$\frac{1}{3}\log(3y+A) = \log(x) + C \Rightarrow \\
\log(3y+A) = 3\log(x) + 3C \Rightarrow \\
3y+A = e^{3\log(x) + 3C} \Rightarrow \\
y = \frac{1}{3}(Dx^3 - A),$$

where $D = e^{3C}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very helpful.
I used the Wolfram alpha website and I got a result of C1 X3-A/3 
So her C1 should be 1/3 exp(3c)? Could you please advise with this

Comment: @shahd Yes. The $C_1$ of Wolfram corresponds to my $\frac{1}{3}e^{3C}$.